# Organise lists of posts by month using Y/m/d

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am making a blog, and I want to be able to filter results based upon the date the post was added. The posts have a datetime in the format 2013-11-15 04:08:03. Now I want to click on a list of months, so let's say I click November it should show all posts in November, but I'm not to sure how I will extract the month from the above time and then add that to a query.

What I've got go so far is a list of months. You select a month that pass's on the numeric value of the month, that is, January = 01. Now that all works, and I can echo out that it works on the net page, but how do I link that with Y/m/d so that the 01 selects all entries with the 01 month?

I was thinking it would be something like select all where m = the selected month (m being the m in Y/m/d).

Comment: Use time as a timestamp!

Comment: @MaciejCzyżewski: why would he use timestamp? What is the difference?

Comment: @Glavić it's not quite big. But I think better solution is use `timestamp` because is more versatile. He need only convert his `Y/m/d` to `timestamp` and execute with simply `>=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all months, in which you have your posts, you can run this simple query:

```sql
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(`date_field`, '%Y%m') AS `id`,
    DATE_FORMAT(`date_field`, '%M %Y') AS `title`
FROM 
    `posts_table`
GROUP BY 
    DATE_FORMAT(`date_field`, '%Y%m')
ORDER BY 
    `date_field` DESC
```

When you fetch this year-months, create links with `id` fetched from previous query, like:

```php
echo '<a href="....?month=' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['title'] . '</a>';
# <a href="....?month=201311">November 2013</a>
```

And when user lands on this link, fetch GET parameter and select all posts for this month:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `posts_table`
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`date_field`, '%Y%m') = ?
```

Where `?` should be selected month, like `201311`. But if you have some index on `date_field`, then you should use `BETWEEN` so index will be applied:

```php
$selected = '201311';
$from = new DateTime("{$selected}01");

$sql = "
    SELECT *
    FROM `posts_table`
    WHERE `date_field` BETWEEN ? AND ?
";
// first  ? should be $from->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
// second ? should be $from->format('Y-m-t 23:59:59');
```

Comment: Thanks for this, coming up with an error ' ''Posts' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT('datetime', '%Y%m') ORDER BY 'datetime' DESC' at line 1 ' i cannot see where ive gone wrong heres the sql SELECT DATE_FORMAT('datetime', '%Y%m') AS 'id',DATE_FORMAT('datetime', '%M %Y') AS 'title' FROM 'Posts' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT('datetime', '%Y%m') ORDER BY 'datetime' DESC


it says there is an extra ' before Posts but there isnt :S

Comment: @jphillip724: you cannot use single quote ( ' ) for aliases, table and field names. You should use back-tick ( ` ), like I did in my answer. If you still have problems, please copy-paste your query to http://pastebin.com/ for better view.